# Getting error "network is unreachable" for Linux GTP module

Tags: linux, networking, kernel-module

I'm trying to build a setup by using GTP module and libgtpnl tools on
Centos 7 but I haven't been successful yet. Worse, I don't know how to
debug the problem. I also stopped firewall and iptables.

What I want to learn how I should approach such a problem? dmesg or
system messages show nothing. Why is an interface unreachable.

Thanks in advance

```
$ modinfo gtp
filename:       
/lib/modules/5.7.7-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/gtp.ko
alias:          net-pf-16-proto-16-family-gtp
alias:          rtnl-link-gtp
description:    Interface driver for GTP encapsulated traffic
author:         Harald Welte <hwelte@sysmocom.de>
license:        GPL
srcversion:     191407DA5399304D93D62C7
depends:        udp_tunnel
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           gtp
vermagic:       5.7.7-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 SMP mod_unload modversions

$ modinfo udp_tunnel
filename:       
/lib/modules/5.7.7-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64/kernel/net/ipv4/udp_tunnel.ko
license:        GPL
srcversion:     0A315BA6124B0664F4D23FB
depends:
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           udp_tunnel
vermagic:       5.7.7-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 SMP mod_unload modversions

$ ip addr add 172.0.0.1/24 dev enp9s0
$ ip addr add 172.99.0.1/32 dev lo

$ ./gtp-link add gtp1
WARNING: attaching dummy socket descriptors. Keep this process running 
for testing purposes.

$ ./gtp-tunnel add gtp1 v1 200 100 172.99.0.2 172.0.0.2
$ ip route add 172.99.0.2/32 dev gtp1

$ ./gtp-tunnel list
version 1 tei 200/100 ms_addr 172.99.0.2 sgsn_addr 172.0.0.2

$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
group default qlen 1000
     link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
     inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
     inet 172.99.0.1/32 scope global lo
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
     inet6 ::1/128 scope host
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: enp9s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state 
UP group default qlen 1000
     link/ether 08:35:71:ab:54:5f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
     inet 172.0.0.1/24 scope global enp9s0
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: gtp1: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 0 qdisc noqueue 
state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
     link/none

$ ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp2s0 proto static metric 100
172.0.0.0/24 dev enp9s0 proto kernel scope link src 172.0.0.1
172.99.0.2 dev gtp1 scope link

$ ping 172.99.0.2
PING 172.99.0.2 (172.99.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MTU for link gtp1 should be set to something other than 0.

Comment: Why? Which effect does that have? How does it solve the problem?

Comment: @Yunnosch The MTU specify the maximum size for packet that can travel through interface. By setting it to 0 linux disable the interface because it is set to lower value than minimal IPv4 or IPv6 packet. That is why you get  Network is unreachable.

Comment: :-) Thanks @Jan. I wanted to hint that answers with explanations are perceived as more helpful... At least now the explanation is here. You are right to not edit it into anohter users answer. I think you could however add your own answer here "Providing an explanation to augment the technically correct answer |linkhere|." By my understanding that would be according to the goals of StackOverflow. (I could not upvote though, because while I believe you, I lack the actual technical knowledge to gauge your explanation.) Have fun.